# java.lang.AssertionError:expected: 1, actual: 0 spring webflow junit

Tags: junit4, easymock, spring-webflow-2

When I call method using EasyMock and set the expectation for the method call, in which method return result is  `Map`.In my test case the return result is not taken by spring webflow. Method is expecting the RequestContext of spring webflow that is `org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext` . I am trying to pass the `MockRequestContext` in junit test case but its not working 
Below is the error

```
  org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@41e68d87 targetAction = [EvaluateAction@49ff7d8c expression = setErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap(flowRequestContext), resultExpression = flowScope.errorMessageMap], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'set_error_in_scope' of flow 'shclogin-flow' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.TransitionExecutingFlowExecutionExceptionHandler.handle(TransitionExecutingFlowExecutionExceptionHandler.java:111)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.FlowExecutionExceptionHandlerSet.handleException(FlowExecutionExceptionHandlerSet.java:109)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleException(Flow.java:600)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.tryFlowHandlers(FlowExecutionImpl.java:647)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleException(FlowExecutionImpl.java:603)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:263)
    at org.springframework.webflow.test.execution.AbstractFlowExecutionTests.resumeFlow(AbstractFlowExecutionTests.java:136)
    at com.shc.ecom.test.usr.TestloginlFlow.testAction(TestloginlFlow.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.ExpressionInvocationTargetException: A problem occurred when trying to execute method 'getErrorMessagesMap' on object of type [com.shc.ecom.sso.cas.web.flow.SetErrorMessages$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$500571b9]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.throwSimpleExceptionIfPossible(MethodReference.java:227)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:133)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call SetErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap([RequestControlContextImpl@c94fd30 externalContext = org.springframework.webflow.test.MockExternalContext@36328d33, currentEvent = [null], requestScope = map[[empty]], attributes = map[[empty]], messageContext = [DefaultMessageContext@2c4d1ac sourceMessages = map[[null] -> list[[empty]]]], flowExecution = [FlowExecutionImpl@7f0d96f2 flow = 'shclogin-flow', flowSessions = list[[FlowSessionImpl@545b995e flow = 'shclogin-flow', state = 'set_error_in_scope', scope = map[[empty]]]]]]):
    SetErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap(flowRequestContext): expected: 1, actual: 0
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
    at com.shc.ecom.sso.cas.web.flow.SetErrorMessages$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$500571b9.getErrorMessagesMap(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129)
    ... 42 more
```

Test Cases

```
public class TestloginlFlow extends AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests {

    UsrInitialFlowSetupAction usrInitialFlowSetupAction;

    AuthenticationViaFormAction authenticationViaFormAction;

    UsrIsSYWRUserCheckAction usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction;

    SSOGatewayService ssoGatewayService;

    CustomGenerateServiceTicketAction generateServiceTicketAction;

    CentralAuthenticationService centralAuthenticateService;

    CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator warnCookieGenerator;

    USRAuthenticationViaFormAction usrAuthenticationViaFormAction;

    List<ArgumentExtractor> argumentExtractor;

    SetErrorMessages setErrorMessages;
    MockRequestContext flowRequestContext;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        usrInitialFlowSetupAction = EasyMock.createMock("usrInitialFlowSetupAction", UsrInitialFlowSetupAction.class); // usrAuthenticationViaFormAction
        setErrorMessages = EasyMock.createMock("SetErrorMessages", SetErrorMessages.class);
        usrAuthenticationViaFormAction = EasyMock.createMock("usrAuthenticationViaFormAction",
                USRAuthenticationViaFormAction.class);
        usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction = EasyMock.createMock("usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction", UsrIsSYWRUserCheckAction.class); // ssoGatewayService

        ssoGatewayService = EasyMock.createMock("ssoGatewayService", SSOGatewayService.class);
        generateServiceTicketAction = EasyMock.createMock("generateServiceTicketAction",
                CustomGenerateServiceTicketAction.class);
        centralAuthenticateService = EasyMock.createMock("centralAuthenticateService",
                CentralAuthenticationService.class);
        warnCookieGenerator = EasyMock.createMock("centralAuthenticateService", CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator.class);
        argumentExtractor = EasyMock.createMock("argumentExtractors", List.class);
        generateServiceTicketAction = EasyMock.createMock("generateServiceTicketAction",
                CustomGenerateServiceTicketAction.class);
        flowRequestContext = EasyMock.createMock("flowRequestContext", MockRequestContext.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected FlowDefinitionResource getResource(FlowDefinitionResourceFactory resourceFactory) {
        return resourceFactory.createFileResource("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/usr/flows/shclogin-flow.xml");
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerMockFlowBeans(ConfigurableBeanFactory builderContext) {
        builderContext.registerSingleton("usrInitialFlowSetupAction", usrInitialFlowSetupAction);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("argumentExtractors", argumentExtractor);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("warnCookieGenerator", warnCookieGenerator);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("centralAuthenticateService", centralAuthenticateService);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("usrAuthenticationViaFormAction", usrAuthenticationViaFormAction);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction", usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("ssoGatewayService", ssoGatewayService);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("generateServiceTicketAction", generateServiceTicketAction);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator", warnCookieGenerator);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("setErrorMessages", setErrorMessages);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("flowRequestContext", flowRequestContext);

    }

    public void testAction1() throws Exception {
        // setCurrentState("initialFlowSetup");
        MockExternalContext ctx = new MockExternalContext();
        MutableAttributeMap input = new LocalAttributeMap();

        input.put("loginId", "12");
        input.put("logonPassword", "ankur");
        input.put("sourceSiteId", "3");
        input.put("fullpage", "");
        input.put("partialuser", "true");
        input.put("service", "");
        input.put("redirectUrl", "");
        input.put("sywLogin", "er4fju");
        input.put("tncmodal", null);
        input.put("modifyservice", "no");
        // input.put("reglogin", false);
        // input.put("enrollresponse", 200);
        input.put("shcCaptchaKey", null);
        input.put("ticketGrantingTicketId", "1234");
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("renew", "yes");
        ParameterMap requestParameterMap = new LocalParameterMap(parameters);
        ctx.setRequestParameterMap(requestParameterMap);
        MockRequestContext context = new MockRequestContext();
        Event event = new Event(this, "success");
    EasyMock.expect(usrInitialFlowSetupAction.doExecute(flowRequestContext)).andReturn(event);
        EasyMock.replay(usrInitialFlowSetupAction);
        /*
         * FlowExecution flowExecution = getFlowExecution(); FlowSession session
         * = flowExecution.getActiveSession();
         * session.getScope().put("ticketGrantingTicketId", "ee");
         */
        // updateFlowExecution(flowExecution);

        startFlow(input, ctx);

    }

    public void testAction() throws Exception {
        setCurrentState("initialFlowSetup");

        FlowExecutionContext flowExecution = getFlowExecution();

        MockRequestContext context = new MockRequestContext();

        MockExternalContext ctx = new MockExternalContext();
        //context.setExternalContext(ctx);
        //context.setFlowExecutionContext(flowExecution);
        //context.setActiveSession(flowExecution.getActiveSession());
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("originalUrl", 123);
        model.put("parameters", "xyz");
        // context.getFlowScope().put("errorMessageMap", model);

        ctx.setEventId("error");
        EasyMock.expect(setErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap(flowRequestContext)).andReturn(model);
        EasyMock.replay(setErrorMessages);

        resumeFlow(ctx);
        assertResponseWrittenEquals("/loginfailure", ctx);
        assertFlowExecutionEnded();

    }

}
```

xml flow

```
    version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.4.xsd" 
              start-state="initialFlowSetup" >


    <input name="loginId" value="requestScope.loginId" />
    <input name="logonPassword" value="requestScope.logonPassword" />
    <input name="sourceSiteId" value="requestScope.sourceSiteId" />
    <input name="fullpage" value="requestScope.fullpage" />
    <input name="partialuser" value="requestScope.partialuser" />
    <input name="sourceSiteId" value="flowScope.sourceSite" />
    <input name="service" value="requestScope.service" />
    <input name="redirectUrl" value="requestScope.redirectUrl" />
    <input name="sywLogin" value="requestScope.sywLogin" />
    <input name="tncmodal" value="requestScope.tncmodal" />
    <input name="modifyservice" value="requestScope.modifyservice" />
    <input name="reglogin" value="flowScope.reglogin" />
    <input name="enrollresponse" value="flowScope.enrollresponse" />
    <input name="shcCaptchaKey" value="requestScope.shcKey" />
    <input name="shcCaptchaResponse" value="requestScope.shcResponse" />
    <input name="sywmax" value="flowScope.sywmax" />
    <input name="auth" value="flowScope.auth" />
    <input name="maxactivationflow" value="flowScope.maxactivationflow" />


    <action-state id="initialFlowSetup">
        <evaluate expression="usrInitialFlowSetupAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="ticketGrantingTicketExistsCheck" />
        <transition on="error" to="pickup_error_redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <decision-state id="ticketGrantingTicketExistsCheck">
        <if test="flowScope.ticketGrantingTicketId != null" then="hasServiceCheck"
            else="gatewayRequestCheck" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="gatewayRequestCheck">
        <if
            test="externalContext.requestParameterMap['gateway'] != '' &amp;&amp; externalContext.requestParameterMap['gateway'] != null &amp;&amp; flowScope.service != null"
            then="redirect" else="submit" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="hasServiceCheck">
        <if test="flowScope.service != null" then="renewRequestCheck"
            else="viewGenericLoginSuccess" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="renewRequestCheck">
        <if
            test="externalContext.requestParameterMap['renew'] != '' &amp;&amp; externalContext.requestParameterMap['renew'] != null"
            then="submit" else="generateServiceTicket" />
    </decision-state>

    <!-- The "warn" action makes the determination of whether to redirect directly 
        to the requested service or display the "confirmation" page to go back to 
        the server. -->
    <decision-state id="warn">
        <if test="flowScope.warnCookieValue" then="showWarningView"
            else="redirect" />
    </decision-state>

    <!-- <action-state id="startAuthenticate"> <action bean="x509Check" /> <transition 
        on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" /> <transition on="error" to="viewLoginForm" 
        /> </action-state> -->
    <view-state id="viewLoginForm" view="casLoginView">
        <on-render>
            <evaluate expression="authenticationViaFormAction.setupForm()" />
            <evaluate expression="authenticationViaFormAction.referenceData()"/>
        </on-render>
        <transition on="submit" to="bindAndValidate" />
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="bindAndValidate">
        <evaluate expression="usrAuthenticationViaFormAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="submit" />
        <transition on="error" to="redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="submit">
        <evaluate expression = "usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.setCredentialsToFlowScope()" />
        <evaluate expression="usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.submit(flowRequestContext, flowScope.credentials, messageContext)" />
        <transition on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" />
        <transition on="authenticationFailure" to="pickup_error_redirect" />
        <transition on="error" to="pickup_error_redirect">
            <set name="errorCode" value="flowScope.errorCode" /> <!--  scope="conversation" />-->
        </transition>
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="sendTicketGrantingTicket">
        <evaluate expression="sendTicketGrantingTicketAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="serviceCheck" />
    </action-state>

    <decision-state id="serviceCheck">
        <if test="flowScope.service != null" then="checkEnrollResponse"
            else="viewGenericLoginSuccess" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="checkEnrollResponse">
        <if test="flowScope.enrollresponse != null" then="generateServiceTicket"
            else="checksywrrequired" />
    </decision-state>

    <!-- select the success modal based on the flow caller -->
    <decision-state id="checksywrrequired">
        <if test="requestScope.sywLogin == 'true'" then="sywrRequired"
            else="generateServiceTicket" />
    </decision-state>

    <action-state id="sywrRequired">
        <evaluate expression="usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="isAffinityCheckRequired" />
        <transition on="error" to="generateServiceTicketNoSywr" />
    </action-state>
    <decision-state id="isAffinityCheckRequired">
        <if test="requestScope.sourceSiteId==6" then="craftsmanAffinityCheck"
            else="generateServiceTicket" />
    </decision-state>
    <action-state id="craftsmanAffinityCheck">
    <evaluate expression="ssoGatewayService.searchUserByMemberNumberInTelluride(flowScope.sywrNumber,
                    requestParameters.sourceSiteId)" result="returnEmailResponse"/>
        <transition on="success" to="checkForCcAffinityModal" />
    </action-state>

    <!-- 
        <bean-action bean="ssoGatewayService" method="searchUserByMemberNumberInTelluride">
            <method-arguments>
                <argument expression="flowScope.sywrNumber" />
                <argument expression="${requestParameters.sourceSiteId}" />
            </method-arguments>
            <method-result name="returnEmailResponse" scope="flow" />
        </bean-action>
     -->

    <decision-state id="checkForCcAffinityModal">
        <if test="flowScope.returnEmailResponse.ccAffinity==true" then="generateServiceTicket"
            else="generateServiceTicketNoCcaffinity" />
    </decision-state>
    <action-state id="generateServiceTicketNoSywr">
        <evaluate expression="generateServiceTicketAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="sendtickettomodalforloginnosywr" />
        <transition on="error" to="setErrorCode" />
        <transition on="gateway" to="redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="generateServiceTicketNoCcaffinity">
        <evaluate expression="generateServiceTicketAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="sendtickettomodalforloginnoccaffinity" />
        <transition on="error" to="setErrorCode" />
        <transition on="gateway" to="redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="generateServiceTicket">
        <evaluate expression="generateServiceTicketAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="pickupticketmodal" />
        <transition on="error" to="setErrorCode" />
        <transition on="gateway" to="redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="setErrorCode">
        <evaluate expression="setErrorCodeBean.submit()" />
        <transition on="success" to="pickup_error_redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <!-- the "viewGenericLogin" is the end state for when a user attempts to 
        login without coming directly from a service. They have only initialized 
        their single-sign on session. -->
    <end-state id="viewGenericLoginSuccess" view="casLoginGenericSuccessView" />

    <!-- The "showWarningView" end state is the end state for when the user 
        has requested privacy settings (to be "warned") to be turned on. It delegates 
        to a view defines in default_views.properties that display the "Please click 
        here to go to the service." message. -->
    <end-state id="showWarningView" view="casLoginConfirmView" />

    <!-- The "redirect" end state allows CAS to properly end the workflow while 
        still redirecting the user back to the service required. -->
    <end-state id="redirect" view="externalRedirect:#{requestScope.response.url}" />

    <end-state id="viewServiceErrorView" view="viewServiceErrorView" />

    <end-state id="viewServiceSsoErrorView" view="viewServiceSsoErrorView" />


    <!-- select the success modal based on the flow caller -->
    <decision-state id="pickupticketmodal">
        <if test="flowScope.enrollresponse != null" then="sendtickettomodal_reg"
            else="sendTicket" />
    </decision-state>

    <!-- send the service ticket back to the modal, no view required in this 
        subflow -->
    <end-state id="sendtickettomodal_reg">
        <output name = "serviceTicketId" value = "requestScope.serviceTicketId"/>
    </end-state>

    <!-- <output-mapper>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.serviceTicketId}" target="serviceTicketId" />
        </output-mapper> -->

    <decision-state id="sendTicket">
        <if test="flowScope.auth != null &amp;&amp; flowScope.auth != ''"
            then="sendtickettomodalforloginnosywr" else="sendtickettomodalforlogin" />
    </decision-state>

    <end-state id="sendtickettomodalforlogin" view="/displayserviceticketandcookie">    
        <output name = "modifyservice" value = "requestScope.modifyservice"/>
        <output name = "sywmax" value = "requestScope.sywmax"/>
        <output name = "irp" value = "requestScope.irp"/>
        <output name = "auth" value = "requestScope.auth"/>
    </end-state>

    <!-- 
        <output-mapper>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.modifyservice}" target="modifyservice"/>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.sywmax}" target="sywmax"/>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.irp}" target="irp"/>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.auth}" target="auth"/>
        </output-mapper>
     -->

    <!-- for login, directly sending the st to the modal -->
    <end-state id="sendtickettomodalforloginnosywr" view="displayserviceticketandcookienosywr" >
        <output name = "modifyservice" value = "requestScope.modifyservice"/>
        <output name = "irp" value = "requestScope.irp"/>
    </end-state>
    <!-- 
        <output-mapper>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.modifyservice}" target="modifyservice" />
            <mapping source="${requestScope.irp}" target="irp" />
        </output-mapper>
     -->
    <end-state id="sendtickettomodalforloginnoccaffinity" view="displayserviceticketandcookienoccaffinity">
        <output name = "modifyservice" value = "requestScope.modifyservice"/>
        <output name = "irp" value = "requestScope.irp"/>
    </end-state>
    <!-- 
        <output-mapper>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.modifyservice}" target="modifyservice" />
            <mapping source="${requestScope.irp}" target="irp" />
        </output-mapper>
     -->

    <!-- for login, directly sending the st to the modal -->
    <end-state id="showTnCModal" view="/showTnCModalToUsers">

    </end-state>
    <!-- select the error redirect based on the flow caller -->
    <decision-state id="pickup_error_redirect">
        <if test="flowScope.enrollresponse != null" then="pickup_error_redirect_reg"
            else="set_error_in_scope" />
    </decision-state>

    <action-state id="set_error_in_scope">
        <evaluate expression="setErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap(flowRequestContext)" result="flowScope.errorMessageMap"
        result-type="java.util.HashMap"></evaluate>
        <transition on="success" to="pickup_error_redirect_login">  </transition>
    </action-state>

      <!-- redirect when error to create sso session, no view required in this subflow -->
    <end-state id="pickup_error_redirect_reg"  />


    <end-state id="pickup_error_redirect_login" view="/loginfailure" >
        <on-entry>
            <set name="flowScope.parameters" value="flowScope.errorMessageMap.parameters"></set>
        </on-entry>
    </end-state>


    <!-- current not properly defined the global error condition -->
    <global-transitions>
        <transition to="pickup_error_redirect"
            on-exception="org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.NoSuchFlowExecutionException" />
        <transition to="pickup_error_redirect"
            on-exception="org.jasig.cas.services.UnauthorizedSsoServiceException" />
        <transition to="pickup_error_redirect"
            on-exception="org.jasig.cas.services.UnauthorizedServiceException" />
        <transition to="pickup_error_redirect"
            on-exception="org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException" />
    </global-transitions>

</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still having the same issues, which are issues with mocking and expecting the exact same object as a parameter.

Why do you care so much about the flowRequestContext object?

```
EasyMock.expect(setErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap(flowRequestContext)).andReturn(model);
```

just use:

```
EasyMock.expect(setErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap((RequestContext)EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(model);
```

which will work with any instance of RequestContext that can be within your flow

Comment: Yeah I did it and it works,  one more thing I would like to ask if you see this  flowScope.ticketGrantingTicketId which is in flow scope,   I am not sure how this will in available in flow scope while writing junit because in our flow we are not setting it anywhere . Can you please tell before starting the flow itself how  we will make available flowScope.ticketGrantingTicketId , flowScope.service etc

Comment: it will be null at the beginning, and it looks like generateServiceTicketAction might be setting this ticketgrantingTicketId. well that would be my guess

Comment: yes that has been set by the method but I have mocked that is there any otherway around to set the flow scope variable before starting the flow

Comment: you can. but if your test aim to replicate a normal execution it's better to mock it. otherwise you are testing a different behavior really